# Count the number of distinct variables in a column for each Code in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to return the number of Y's N's and R's for each Code in redshift SQL.
Table:

```
Code  Allowed?
 A       Y
 A       Y
 A       N
 A       Y
 A       R
 A       Y
 A       N
 A       R
 B       Y
 B       N
 B       Y
```

Desired Output:

```
Code Count_Y  Count_N  Count_R
 A      4        2        2
 B      2        1        0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select code, sum( (allowed = 'Y')::int ) as num_y,
       sum( (allowed = 'N')::int ) as num_n,
       sum( (allowed = 'R')::int ) as num_r
from t
group by code;
```